# Android- string not added after second

Tags: java, android, string

I am trying to append few strings in android, I don't know why after second-string it does not work, the following is the code.

```
 String code_challenge = CryptoHash.getSHA256(code_verifier);
            Log.d(code_challenge,"Code challange");

            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(100);
            s.append(URL);
            s.append(code_verifier);
            s.append("&code_challenge=");
            s.append(code_challenge);
            s.append("&code_challenge_method=S256");


            String OAuthURL = URL + code_verifier + "&code_challenge=" + code_challenge + "&code_challenge_method=S256";
            Log.d(OAuthURL,"test");
            Log.d(s.toString(),"test2");
```

it is giving me the following result in log.

```
http://10.0.2.2:4431/OAuth/Login?response_type=code&state=Es0wjDVkhRwQ7kTM2TMPO6EJXoCgk
```

What's wrong with this code?

Following is the log

```
2020-03-17 17:08:33.600 15174-15196/com.example.oauthdemo I/ample.oauthdem: Background concurrent copying GC freed 4427(899KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(80KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 1639KB/3MB, paused 5.380ms total 57.233ms
2020-03-17 17:08:33.615 15174-15174/com.example.oauthdemo D/Es0wjDVkhRwQ7kTM2TMPO6EJXoCgkfxNeheKcftc: Code Verifier
2020-03-17 17:08:33.616 15174-15174/com.example.oauthdemo D/236531d42fc589f28f7024f250eb6164764ffd1714057eb95429539eab4d316b: Code challange

    [          1584445113.616 15174:15174 D/http://10.0.2.2:4431/OAuth/Login?response_type=code&state=Es0wjDVkhRwQ7kTM2TMPO6EJXoCgktest

    [          1584445113.616 15174:15174 D/http://10.0.2.2:4431/OAuth/Login?response_type=code&state=Es0wjDVkhRwQ7kTM2TMPO6EJXoCgktest2
2020-03-17 17:08:33.643 15174-15174/com.example.oauthdemo D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
```

Please help!

Comment: pleas explain more what you want and what went wrong?

Comment: please add all the logs

Comment: please check, edited

Comment: The full string should be like this...  http://10.0.2.2:4431/OAuth/Login?response_type=code&state=Es0wjDVkhRwQ7kTM2TMPO6EJXoCgk&code_challenge=236531d42fc589f28f7024f250eb6164764ffd1714057eb95429539eab4d316b&code_challenge_method=S256

Comment: you are setting limit to StringBuilder when instantiating the instance, remove the 100 char limit.

Answer (score 1):

you should remove the limit or increase it

```
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
```

best wishes for you

Comment: remove the length make it default constructor new StringBuilder()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing arguments to `Log.d` method in incorrect order. Change to `Log.d("test2", s.toString());`, because tag you are passing has max symbols restriction